# Issue with proguardFile, null returned: 1

Tags: android, ant, proguard

Hi am trying to run "ant clean debug" command on cmd. But i am getting null returned: 1 error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:622: The following error    occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:658: null returned: 1



 <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                 command="package"
                 verbose="${verbose}"
                 manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                 androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                 rfolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
                 nonConstantId="${android.library}"
                 libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                 libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                 ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
                 proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
             <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
             <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
         </aapt>
```

the line no 658 :

```
 proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
```

the line no 622 :

```
 elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java">
```

Is their anybody their who know the solution for this issue.

Comment: Please rename your question's title. Include proguard somewhere.

Comment: // proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt" // This line has the problem. Most recent Proguard changes reference the proguard configuration file as proguard-project.txt within the Project root directory. When does this file get copied to {out.absolute.dir}, and when does the name change to proguard.txt. This seems like a bug from google android sdk ant build tools.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there also was an error report earlier in the logs, it was just difficult to find.
As I understand, any kind of error would lead to that message.

So the crazy message `null returned: 1` actually means ***please read the above logs***.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when referencing an external legacy library form my main project - after referencing, my main project would not build, although both built fine when not referencing the external one.

The solution, idiotic as it is, was to create a new empty Android app project and copy all the sources and resource files from the external library in the new project. Afterwards, the referencing works and everything builds fine.

I believe this is related to [changes in Proguard after ADT 17](http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements).

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\` this path contains spaces.
Remove spaces from sdk path.

You can use like `c:\Android\android-sdk`.. for your sdk path that doesn't contain any space.

Comment: hmm agree, its better to put SDK in parent path *C:\, D:\ etc.*

Comment: do you mean space in Program Files (x86)?

Comment: yes i am using "" with Program Files (x86). like this "Program Files (x86)". Like this C:\Users\srcloud\Documents\GitHub\SalesforceMobileSDK-Android\native\SalesforceSDK>C:\"Program Files
 (x86)"\Android\android-sdk\tools\android update project -p . -t 1

Comment: change it to a different path where there is no space like c:/android-sdk

Comment: I done the same way you guide me but getting the same error.           BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:622: The following error occurred while executing this li
ne:
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:658: null returned: 1

Comment: Download the latest version of proguard and try again

Comment: Yes i did it, edited the project.properties in the file i removed the  #proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt but the output is BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:622: The following error occurred while executing this li
ne:
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:658: null returned: 1

Comment: you want to build your app?

Comment: i downloaded it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/?source=dlp but still the error is their 
BUILD FAILED
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:622: The following error occurred while executing this li
ne:
C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:658: null returned: 1

Comment: you mean like this C:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4>C:\Android\android-sdk\tools\android update project -p . -t 1

Comment: yes, like this.and after entering the path if you want to build ant debug <path of project manifest> like ant debug D:/srt/allproject/MyApp/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes i did it see the command C:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4>C:\Users\srcloud\Documents\GitHub\SalesforceMobileSDK-A
ndroid\hybrid\SampleApps\SFDCAccounts\AndroidManifest.xml but nothing is coming C:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4>

Comment: C:\ant\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4>ant debug C:\Users\srcloud\Documents\GitHub\S‌​alesforceMobileSDK-A ndroid\hybrid\SampleApps\SFDCAccounts\AndroidManifest.xml